# Converting list to formatted string, then writing string to text file in said format

Tags: python, string, list

I need to convert a list into a string which I want to format as follows:

```
Enter your Account Number: 1
l 0.0 l
2 0.0 2
3 0.0 3
4 0.0 4
```

I then want to write that string into a text file keeping the same format.

```
account= ["a1", "a2", "a3"]
balance= ["b1", "b2", "b3"]
names= ["n1", "n2", "n3"]

length = len(account)

i = 0
for i in range(i, length):
    new_list = ''.format(account[i] + " " + balance[i] + " " + names[i])
    print(new_list)
    i += 1
string = new_list

data_file = open("bank.txt", 'a')
data_file.write(str(string))
data_file.close()
```

If I print the string, it prints out in the right format, but only the last line of the string is written to the text file.

Comment: You need to put the for-loop between the opening and the closing of the file.

Comment: You need to use '\n' if you write to a file.

Comment: If you just run your code in the Python interpreter (using [IPython](http://ipython.readthedocs.io) is the best), you'll see that `string` is `''`.

Comment: @sequeL Welcome to [so]! Please type your format into your question, instead of sharing a link. This makes it much easier for someone to answer your question, and helps future readers, even if the link disappears one day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code:

```
account= ["a1", "a2", "a3"]
balance= ["b1", "b2", "b3"]
names= ["n1", "n2", "n3"]

length = len(account)
data_file = open("bank.txt", 'w')

for i in range(length):
    new_list = '{} {} {}\n'.format(account[i], balance[i], names[i])
    data_file.write(new_list)
data_file.close()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, been trying to find the solution for the past 4 hours